# Discord.py Intents makes my bot not respond to anything

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

After the 1.5 update, nothing will work, i added the intents, and privileged intents are on. Events or commands won't work now

I have this:

```
intents = discord.Intents()
intents.all()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
```

My bot wont respond to anything. Thanks in advance

Comment: try `intents = discord.Intents.all()`.. [Link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#what-intents-are-needed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it now, it was just a stupid bug unrelated to discord.py that went under the radar

Answer (score 0):

You Must enable the intents according to what you are going to use in your bot code! or it may not work properly without enabling this! [image]

Comment: Yeah, i have tried that.. But then it's just running random pieces of code, that has nothing to do with the command being typed. 2 users in my discord got randomly banned now for typing a command that doesn't even have the word "ban" in it lol.
thx for answering tho